# jupyter notebook, export cell

Tags: python, d3.js, svg, jupyter

Does someone know how to export/save the displayed HTML cell of a jupyter notebook into a file?

Or alternatively (Even better), to save a created D3 figure as an svg?

I was thinking maybe it's possible to retrieve only the svg element to export it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try, `select the cell` --> `File` --> `Download as .html`

Comment: and programmatically? but, with the download as .html doesn't work - it save with that empty cell. Maybe I should give more details: the cell is the result of using d3.js inside HTML - i do see it in the notebook, but then I wonder if I can somehow retrieve that cell, or the .svg element?